# I'd like to write a custom error handling for node api

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest

I'd like to code a custom error handling for error codes so I can easily response with defined static necessary information. I need some help because I don't know how am I supposed to do such a feature.

Code would look like following:

```
 if (some_condition) {
    response.status(200); // success
    }
 else {
    response.status(400); //error
    }
```

and then in the main script:

```
// if get response.status(400) then reply with following json:

{
    'success': false,
    'code': 400,
    'info': "Bad request."
}
```

Comment: You can throw the error, right? It should work just fine in the console, and to handle it.

Comment: @MrMythical I don't want to get the error in the console, I wanna throw it in a json as a response

Comment: I don’t understand. Where do you want to see the error exactly?

Comment: I want to see it as response.json, but that is not what I'm asking for. I just would like to make a static reply for the 400 error so that I wouldn't have to write it every time I wanna throw it

Comment: is it a different file? What is wrong with your current code?

Comment: the bad thing is that I have to enter data that could be static

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using Express or the built-in http module?

With Express you can throw an error and handle it in the error handling middleware (usually the last middleware to be applied).

Throw the error where ever you need to:

```
const error = new Error('Your error message');
error.statusCode = 400;
throw error;
```

Handle the error:

```
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    const { statusCode = 500 } = err;
    if (!err.message) err.message = 'Bad Request';
    const message = {
        'success': false,
        'code': statusCode,
        'info': err.message
    }
    res.status(statusCode).json(message);
});
```

Comment: I use express, and that's what I'm looking for, thank you so much!